# Correct format for writing conditionals in ruby and then converting output into string using string interpolation inside HAML tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, haml, string-interpolation

I am fixing a bug in a ruby on rails open source project at the front end of the project. I am a newbie to ruby on rails, HAML etc. The following line of code is giving me a lot of trouble.

I am wondering what would be correct way to format this. Further, is there a way to write a helper function to turn the conditionals into a function call? Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried several formats but the devs want me to break up the if-else into several lines. I am unable to make that work.

```
6:       %strong =
7:       "#{
8:         - if @enterprise.is_primary_producer
9:           = t('.producer_profile')
10:         - else
11:           = t('.profile')
```

I expect the view to be rendered but instead I get syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
%strong
  - if @enterprise.is_primary_producer
    = t('.producer_profile')
  - else
    = t('.profile')
```

Personally, I would do something like:

```
- t_key = @enterprise.is_primary_producer ? '.producer_profile' : '.profile'
%strong= t(t_key)
```

If you want to move this to a helper, just define it somewhere like in application_helper.rb

```
def some_name_for_the_method(enterprise)
  t_key = enterprise.is_primary_producer ? '.producer_profile' : '.profile'
  I18n.t(t_key)
end
```

and on the view

```
%strong= some_name_for_the_method(@enterprise)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up coming up with your first suggestion but I was wondering about how to make the alternate approaches you have mentioned. I appreciate the help and lesson!